# MVC3 :: Using global.asax to direct a specific controller/action to a different controller/action

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, routes

In an MVC3 app I have a view in my home controller that is accessed via the following URL:

http://mysite.com/home/mycontent

However, my user wants to accees it via:

http://mysite.com/mycontent (without a specific reference to the home controller)

I've tried modifying my global.asax with the following:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        "MyContent", // Route name
        "MyContent", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Home", action = "MyContent"} // Parameter defaults
    );
```

But I get 404 errors when I try to use it.  Is there a way I can accomplish what my user is wanting to do - redirecting a URL to a specific controller/view pair?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should keep some "parameters":

```
routes.MapRoute(
        "MyContent", // Route name
        "{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Home", action = "MyContent", id = ""} // Parameter defaults
    );
```

Comment: Sorry ... but still the same problem.

Comment: Do you define some other routes (may be a default one) ?

Comment: NvrMind ... I got it ... I figured it out and used "MyContent" instead of "{action}/{id}"

Answer (score 1):

In what order are your routes registered? That route should come before your default route.

E.g.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "MyContent", // Route name
    "MyContent", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "MyContent"} // Parameter defaults
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Pages", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Otherwise, it should work... I have routes defined exactly the same as that.